# Using Arrays.asList and compare

Tags: android, arrays, string

I have an array like the next:

```
this.ntpServers[0][0] = "Global";
this.ntpServers[0][1] = "pool.ntp.org";
this.ntpServers[1][0] = "Africa";
this.ntpServers[1][1] = "africa.pool.ntp.org";
this.ntpServers[2][0] = "Asia";
this.ntpServers[2][1] = "asia.pool.ntp.org";
this.ntpServers[3][0] = "Europe";
this.ntpServers[3][1] = "europe.pool.ntp.org";
this.ntpServers[4][0] = "North America";
...
this.ntpServers[85][0] = ...
this.ntpServers[85][1] = ...
```

I have in another String a country, and I am trying to use the next code to compare if exist in the list, but Iit doesn't returns me a true, when it must be true. If I check for "Asia" it would be true. But something is wrong.

gettedCountry is a String

```
public int existNTP(String[][] list) {

    if(Arrays.asList(list).contains(gettedCountry)){

        Log.i("Found", "Found");

        }

        return position;
    }
```

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(list)` will return an `ArrayList` of `String[]` not `String`. If you need to check for the first item:

```
ArrayList<String[]> arr=Arrays.asList(list);

for(String[] arry : arr){
  if(arry[0].equals(gettedCountry)) /* Do your stuff */;
}
```

Comment: But the docs sais that it will return true if contains the object.

Comment: Yes, but you the objects you are searching in are String array objects not Strings, so you are making a check like (String[] == String)

Comment: `ArrayList<String[]> arr=Arrays.asList(list);` is not needed. you can directly iterate over `arr`

Answer (score 1):

Either make proper objects to turn your two-dimentional array into a list (recommended)

OR

iterate over your array:

```
int position = 0;
for (String[] entry : ntpServers) {
  if (entry[0].equals(country)) return position;
  ++position;
}

return -1; // Not found is an invalid position like -1
```

Comment: Yes I did it, but I read a post here, that says that Arrays.asList for comparisons are faster and more efficient than this way.

Comment: I'd be curious to get that reference. Seems weird